# How to write while loop into another while loop for fetch data from SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from two different queries, so first I get data by writing this code:

```
$sql = "select DATE_FORMAT(tr_date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as tr_date,p1,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,tno from rnb_gpl_data where DATE_FORMAT(tr_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= '$s' AND DATE_FORMAT(tr_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <= '$e' and did = '$did' order by srno desc limit $offse, $rec_limi";

$retval = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$sqlll = "select * from rnb1_data where DATE_FORMAT(tr_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') >= '$s' AND DATE_FORMAT(tr_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') <= '$e' and did = '$did' limit $offse, $rec_limi";

$retval11 = mysqli_query($con, $sqlll);

if(! $retval11 ) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while($rowww = mysqli_fetch_array($retval11, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $bit = $rowww['bitumen_tph'];
    $netmixt= $rowww['netmix'];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $jv1=$row['p1'];
        echo "<tr > ".

        "<td class=\"center\">$jv1</td> ".
        "<td class=\"center\">$bit</td> ".
        "<td class=\"center\">$netmixt</td> ".
    }
}
```

But my netmixt and bit value remain same for all record. Only jv1 value change according to my database record. I want to update all data according to my database table.

[image]

In this image first column is jv1 value second is bit and third is netmix.

You can see that bit and netmix value remain same for all rows but actually it differ in database table.

Comment: Hey, I am not sure but i think you should try this`while($rowww = mysqli_fetch_array($retval11, MYSQL_ASSOC) || $row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $bit = $rowww['bitumen_tph'];
     $netmixt= $rowww['netmix'];
        $jv1=$row['p1'];
        echo "<tr > ".

        "<td class=\"center\">$jv1</td> ".
        "<td class=\"center\">$bit</td> ".
        "<td class=\"center\">$netmixt</td> ".
}`

Comment: its not working

Comment: Are counts of rows in both queries the same?

Comment: yes..srno no is same for both.